# How to access the stored drawing commands of a Path object in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to access the stored paint commands of a Path (from dart:ui) object? It seems that all functions which manipulate the Path directly are processed in in C++ layer calling the Skia API.

I would like to do something like this:

```dart
String convertToSvgPath(Path path){
   ///
}
```

Output:

```
>>$ This is a path: "M86 189l-1-1h-2l-2-1h-1l-3z"
```

Comment: why would you want `"M86 189l-1-1h-2l-2-1h-1l-3z"`?

Comment: for example to export a Path object as an svg file or to manipulate the path and store it as a new path object

Comment: if you have a `Path` object, it is not taken from "outside" but it is created by you so you know what `Path` methods were called on that object - or you got `Path` object as a result of some "black-box-package"? if the latter you cannot do anything with that, sorry

Comment: I would like to do the latter e.g. use path.addRect() and then access/manipulate the resulting path object. For the engine this seems possible see e.g. the path.shift(...) method

Comment: this is because it can keep the commands internally but does not provide any api to iterate over them by `Path` public API, if you have a `Path` already created and filled with shapes you cannot do anything but if you are creating that `Path` object in **your** code you could create a class that extends `Path` class and override any method to keep track what shapes were added to your custom `Path`